# Tidyverse change values based on name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

#df <- read_csv("C:\\Users\\omarl\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\games.csv")

df <- structure(list(gameId = 3326086514, creationTime = 1504279457970, 
                     gameDuration = 1949, seasonId = 9, winner = 1, firstBlood = 2, 
                     firstTower = 1, firstInhibitor = 1, firstBaron = 1, firstDragon = 1, 
                     firstRiftHerald = 2, t1_champ1id = 8, t1_champ1_sum1 = 12, 
                     t1_champ1_sum2 = 4, t1_champ2id = 432, t1_champ2_sum1 = 3, 
                     t1_champ2_sum2 = 4, t1_champ3id = 96, t1_champ3_sum1 = 4, 
                     t1_champ3_sum2 = 7, t1_champ4id = 11, t1_champ4_sum1 = 11, 
                     t1_champ4_sum2 = 6, t1_champ5id = 112, t1_champ5_sum1 = 4, 
                     t1_champ5_sum2 = 14, t1_towerKills = 11, t1_inhibitorKills = 1, 
                     t1_baronKills = 2, t1_dragonKills = 3, t1_riftHeraldKills = 0, 
                     t1_ban1 = 92, t1_ban2 = 40, t1_ban3 = 69, t1_ban4 = 119, 
                     t1_ban5 = 141, t2_champ1id = 104, t2_champ1_sum1 = 11, t2_champ1_sum2 = 4, 
                     t2_champ2id = 498, t2_champ2_sum1 = 4, t2_champ2_sum2 = 7, 
                     t2_champ3id = 122, t2_champ3_sum1 = 6, t2_champ3_sum2 = 4, 
                     t2_champ4id = 238, t2_champ4_sum1 = 14, t2_champ4_sum2 = 4, 
                     t2_champ5id = 412, t2_champ5_sum1 = 4, t2_champ5_sum2 = 3, 
                     t2_towerKills = 5, t2_inhibitorKills = 0, t2_baronKills = 0, 
                     t2_dragonKills = 1, t2_riftHeraldKills = 1, t2_ban1 = 114, 
                     t2_ban2 = 67, t2_ban3 = 43, t2_ban4 = 16, t2_ban5 = 51), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(winner = ifelse(winner == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  mutate(firstBlood = ifelse(firstBlood  == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  mutate(firstTower = ifelse(firstTower == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  mutate(firstInhibitor = ifelse(firstInhibitor == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  mutate(firstBaron = ifelse(firstBaron == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  mutate(firstDragon = ifelse(firstDragon == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  mutate(firstRiftHerald = ifelse(firstRiftHerald == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>%
  select(-gameId, -creationTime) %>%
  filter(seasonId == 9) %>%
  select(gameDuration, winner, firstBlood, firstTower, firstInhibitor, firstBaron, firstDragon,
         firstRiftHerald)
```

As you can see, mutate is really redundant here, because I'm copying the code for every variable. Is there any way to apply the `ifelse` to columns that start with `first`, `t1`, etc. programatically?

Comment: yes …check ?across

Comment: Just a small note about the *minimal* part of [mcve]: tidymodels isn't used in the scope of this question, so you could take loading it out of the question. One less dependency for folks to have in order to run your code

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("t1")|starts_with("first"), ~ifelse(.x == 1, "team1", "team2")))
```

Comment: Any difference with using `map`?

Answer (score 0):

Park gave a best (one liner) solution. But if you want to look at some other options, here is how we can do it via using some other functions in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, firstBlood:t1_ban5) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == 1, "team1", "team2")) %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  select(-gameId, -creationTime) %>%
  filter(seasonId == 9) %>%
  select(gameDuration, winner, firstBlood, firstTower, firstInhibitor, firstBaron, firstDragon,
         firstRiftHerald)
```